# How to solve "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" when using tigase.jaxmpp.j2se.Jaxmpp 3.0.0

Tags: java, exception, xmpp, socketexception, tigase

I have written a JAXMPPClient.java program which uses tigase.jaxmpp.j2se.Jaxmpp 3.0.0

I have the following .jar files in my build path

```
jaxmpp-core-3.0.0
jaxmpp-j2se-3.0.0
```

and folder jaxmpp-all-3.0.0 containing many .jar files. The JAXMPPClient.java is as follows

```
Jaxmpp conn = new Jaxmpp();
conn.getConnectionConfiguration().setConnectionType(
    ConnectionType.socket);
conn.getConnectionConfiguration().setDomain(IP_ADDRESS_OF_XMPP_SERVER);
conn.getConnectionConfiguration().setPort(PORT_NUMBER_OF_XMPP_SERVER);
conn.getConnectionConfiguration().setUserJID(FROM_USERID + "@" +
    IP_ADDRESS_OF_XMPP_SERVER);
conn.getConnectionConfiguration().setUserPassword(FROM_PASSWORD);

String s = tigase.jaxmpp.j2se.connectors.socket.
    SocketConnector.HOSTNAME_VERIFIER_DISABLED_KEY
conn.getSessionObject().setProperty(s, Boolean.TRUE);

try {
    System.out.println("Before login");
    conn.login();
    System.out.println("After login");
} catch (final JaxmppException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting

```
Before login
Sep 29, 2015 5:17:12 PM tigase.jaxmpp.j2se.Jaxmpp createConnector
INFO: Using SocketConnector
Sep 29, 2015 5:17:12 PM tigase.jaxmpp.j2se.connectors.socket.SocketConnector start
INFO: Resolving SRV recrd of domain '123.45.678.910'
Sep 29, 2015 5:17:12 PM tigase.jaxmpp.j2se.connectors.socket.SocketConnector start
INFO: Opening connection to /123.45.678.910:5222
Sep 29, 2015 5:17:12 PM tigase.jaxmpp.j2se.connectors.socket.Worker run
WARNING: Exception in worker
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at tigase.jaxmpp.j2se.connectors.socket.TextStreamReader.read(TextStreamReader.java:49)
    at tigase.jaxmpp.j2se.connectors.socket.Worker.run(Worker.java:99)

After login
```

The IP Address, Port number, From JabberID and Password are correct and are working fine from iOS and Android Apps. Also I am able to successfully ping the Tigase server IP address.

From where is the java.net.SocketException being thrown ? How can I fix this problem ?